# How to center the navigation drop down in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a theme using Twitter Bootstrap, and I'm trying to get the drop down navigation to be centered instead of left-aligned. To be clear: I'm talking about centering the whole drop down box relative to its parent, not about centering the text inside the box.

The markup looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav ww-nav pull-right hidden-phone">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Words</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Articles</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Published</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categorized</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Award Winning</a></li>
    </ul>                   
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

To clarify what I mean, I'll attach a screenshot:

[image: Bootstrap dropdown menu]

**Note:** I'm looking for a general solution, that works with different parent items. Since it is a theme, the navigation items can be anything from 3 characters to 20 characters wide. A simple margin by X pixels doesn't cut it, unfortunately.

PS: As requested in the comments, I put the whole thing on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zdCYX/4/

Thanks

Comment: do you want to center elements or??

Comment: @Shail: No, not the elements. I mean the whole green box.

Comment: @abbood: I updated the question with the jsfiddle link. See at the very end.

Comment: @Mint Buddy I have posted a jsfiddle , please check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this using jQuery, calculating and adjusting the margin-left of every sub menu.

This way my navigation items have the same space between each other.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        $("ul.ww-nav ul.dropdown-menu").each(function(){
            var parentWidth = $(this).parent().innerWidth();
            var menuWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
            var margin = (parentWidth / 2 ) - (menuWidth / 2);
            margin = margin + "px";
            $(this).css("margin-left", margin);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: HOw can there be irregular space between li items when I have fixed width between them

Comment: The padding and margin between them will always be the same no matter what, as they have same classes .

Comment: @Shail: That is exactly why there are irregular spaces between the items. You fix the width at 116px, so when the items have different character lengths, it will appear irregular. Just look at your own JSFiddle Demo: The space between Link and Link is bigger than the space between Link and Dropdown (for Dropdown having more characters).

Comment: Cheers for this snippet, really helped my brain - Can I suggest that you declare all the local variables with var? (i.e. var parentWidth, var menuWidth) - they’re being declared as global variables here and could interfere with other code if someone copy-and-pastes this without thinking!

Comment: @ChrisS: You're absolutely right of course. I updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Jsfiddle [Demo in browser](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/h56LW/show/)
What you can do is set the width to the main nav element and than to the drop down : like following :

```
 .navbar .nav > li {

   width: 116px;
     }

.dropdown-menu {
      display:none;
      width:116px;
      min-width:116px;
      margin:0 auto;
  }
```

You will have to change the following code align elements

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
         text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That just centers the text within the drop down, not the drop down itself. I have this in place already (see screenshot).

Comment: Please see last paragraph in my question. A fixed offset won't help, since the parent items can be of any size (it is a theme). It should work without adjusting CSS for every drop down.

Comment: Thanks Shail, but this still uses fixed width and is thus not really compatible with items of varying width. Also in your demo, the spaces between the top navigation items are irregular. I solved it using Javascript. See my answer.